# intel xdk quit mobile app on back button click

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova, intel-xdk

I have made an app using intel xdk. The default behaviour of mobile's inbuilt back button redirects me on the page according to history. It behaves just like a web browser back button, because my code is in html5 format.

However, I want my app to exit/quit on click of back button. I am not any of the using cordova plugins.

I want to use back button to quit application. How can i do this.

Answer (score 3):

In cordova, when the device is ready, you can add an even listener to the back button  like this:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", backButtonPressed, false);
```

Now the JavaScript `backButtonPressed()` function will be called when the user presses the back button, so you just need to define it in your code, and use `navigator.app.exitApp()` inside of it to exit the app. The resulting code would look like this:

```
function backButtonPressed() {

    // Optionally, processes before quitting the app: save variables, log changes, etc.
    ...

    // exit the application
    navigator.app.exitApp();

}
```